# Requests to Google API stopped working, How can I debug the issue?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-calendar-api

Our service uses Google Calendar API to get events from multiple google accounts.
Those google accounts belong to our customers, they granted us with relevant permission.
The grant is given to an OAuth 2.0 Client of a specific project on our Google cloud account.

I'm using a [Ruby](https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-ruby-client) library and while debugging I was able to reproduce the issue:

```
client = Google::APIClient.new(:application_name => 'vCita', :application_version => 'Production')
client.authorization.client_id = "XXX.apps.googleusercontent.com"
client.authorization.client_secret = "XXX"
client.authorization.access_token = "XXX"
client.authorization.refresh_token = "XXX"
document_base = client.discovery_uri('calendar', 'v3')
response = client.execute!(
    :http_method => :get,
    :uri => document_base,
    :authenticated => false
)
response.data
```

Response:

```
<Google::APIClient::Result:0x0055ca4a090488 @request=#<Google::APIClient::Request:0x0055ca4a15b0c0 @parameters={}, @headers={"User-Agent"=>"vCita/Production google-api-ruby-client/0.6.4 Linux/4.15.0-1050-aws"}, @api_method=nil, @authenticated=false, @authorization=nil, @body="", @http_method=:get, @uri=#<Addressable::URI:0x2ae5250ad734 URI:https://www.googleapis.com/discovery/v1/apis/calendar/v3/rest>>, @response=#<Faraday::Response:0x0055ca4a090528 @env={:method=>:get, :body=>"<HTML><HEAD><meta http-equiv=\"content-type\" content=\"text/html;charset=utf-8\">\n<TITLE>302 Moved</TITLE></HEAD><BODY>\n<H1>302 Moved</H1>\nThe document has moved\n<A HREF=\"https://www.google.com/sorry/index?continue=https://www.googleapis.com/discovery/v1/apis/calendar/v3/rest&amp;q=EgQ2VD-rGKaTvvgFIhkA8aeDS9sKbMBCFduKBeOfzZAR8ZN7WerwMgFj\">here</A>.\r\n</BODY></HTML>\r\n", :url=>#<URI::HTTPS:0x0055ca4a121d20 URL:https://www.googleapis.com/discovery/v1/apis/calendar/v3/rest>, :request_headers=>{"User-Agent"=>"X/Y google-api-ruby-client/0.6.4 Linux/4.15.0-1050-aws", "Content-Type"=>"application/x-www-form-urlencoded"}, :parallel_manager=>nil, :request=>{:proxy=>nil}, :ssl=>{}, :status=>302, :response_headers=>{"location"=>"https://www.google.com/sorry/index?continue=https://www.googleapis.com/discovery/v1/apis/calendar/v3/rest&q=EgQ2VD-rGKaTvvgFIhkA8aeDS9sKbMBCFduKBeOfzZAR8ZN7WerwMgFj", "date"=>"Wed, 15 Jul 2020 22:56:38 GMT", "pragma"=>"no-cache", "expires"=>"Fri, 01 Jan 1990 00:00:00 GMT", "cache-control"=>"no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate", "content-type"=>"text/html; charset=UTF-8", "server"=>"HTTP server (unknown)", "content-length"=>"365", "x-xss-protection"=>"0", "alt-svc"=>"h3-29=\":443\"; ma=2592000,h3-27=\":443\"; ma=2592000,h3-25=\":443\"; ma=2592000,h3-T050=\":443\"; ma=2592000,h3-Q050=\":443\"; ma=2592000,h3-Q046=\":443\"; ma=2592000,h3-Q043=\":443\"; ma=2592000,quic=\":443\"; ma=2592000; v=\"46,43\"", "connection"=>"close"}, :response=>#<Faraday::Response:0x0055ca4a090528 ...>}, @on_complete_callbacks=[]>>
```

Whats interesting here is the redirect:

```
https://www.google.com/sorry/index?continue=https://www.googleapis.com/discovery/v1/apis/calendar/v3/rest&q=EgQ2VD-rGKaTvvgFIhkA8aeDS9sKbMBCFduKBeOfzZAR8ZN7WerwMgFj
```

[Error Page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EhsCl.png)

Any suggestions on how to debug this issue?
I've been trying to resolve this issue with Google support without success.

Please advise,
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It appears like a bug on Google calendar API.
We received a human facing CAPTCHA response while trying to discover the Calendar API:

```
client.discovery_uri('calendar', 'v3')
```

For more details, please refer to:
https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/159368649#comment66